# Web2py : "Premature end of script headers: wsgihandler.py" : apache eating cpu 99%

Tags: jquery-mobile, apache2, mod-wsgi, web2py

I've suddenly started seeing this in the logs & I see that RAM usage goes through the roof and apache is consuming all of it.

Also, after googling I added the below in my **sites-available** in apache :

`WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`

Didn't seem to have helped though..

Some more info. in case it helps :
**OS** : Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
**Memory** : 512 MB RAM
**Web2py version** : Version 1.99.7 (2012-03-04 22:12:08) stable
**psycopg2** version : 2.4.5

**IMP :** I just noticed that it started happening only after I started accessing the site from iphone after making one of the pages jquery_mobile enabled !

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue?